# How can I hide passwords in Thruk?

Tags: nagios, thruk

So Thruk now has an option to obfuscate passwords and other sensitive information in the "Expanded command" field. I've turned that option on, but it doesn't appear to have done anything. I edited the thruk_local.conf file to add the code included in Thruk: `commandline_obfuscate_pattern = /(\-\-password=")[^"]*(")/$1"***"$2/` but I don't read Perl so I have no idea how to look into why it's failing. I know Perl is installed, but is this script looking for a specific pattern to replace? In the command, the password is denoted with a "-p". Hoping someone here has used this before and can help me out!

Comment: Update: The script had to be updated with this pattern: /(\-p\s)[^\s]*(\s)/$1******$2/ and it worked! It replaces the password that followed "-p" with ******

Answer (score 0):

If you use NAGIOS or fork like this, you can put password in /usr/local/nagios/private/resources.cfg with $USER100$ tu $USER2xx$
And then in thruk add this option in /etc/thruk/thruk_local.conf :
resource_file=/etc/thruk/resource.cfg (where $USER1$ to $USER99$ that will be show)
expand_user_macros = USER1-99

This add security to your password in nagios